# CasperJS loop through table and scrape data for JSON output

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm actually trying to get some data from a website in CasperJs. The datas are stocked in a table. 
I'm trying to get a proper JSON file after the scrap. A json with :
- name of the company, 
- mail, 
- website 
- description of activity.

Until now I've been able to open the page and get the  data but not precisely (mail and website are on the same ). So I've found how to select precisely each element I want. 
But in this case I don't get all table information's,  only first row...

I would know if somebody could help me, telling me where to look or how to make loop in my case ? Assume I'm not a professional developper, I'm training myself.

Here my code :

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'http://www.rent2016.fr/pages/exposants';
var fs = require('fs');
var length;

casper.start(url);

casper.then(function() {
    this.waitForSelector('table#myTable');
});

casper.then(function(){
    var info = this.evaluate(function(){
        var table_rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr"); //or better selector

        return Array.prototype.map.call(table_rows, function(tr){
            return {

                nom : document.querySelector(".td-width h3").textContent,
                description: document.querySelector(".td-width p").textContent,
                mail : document.querySelector("td span a").textContent,
                site : document.querySelector('td span a[href^="http"]').textContent,



            };
        });
    });

  fs.write('test_rent_stringify.json', JSON.stringify(info), 'w');
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(info, undefined, 4));

});


casper.run(function() {

});
```

Here, we don't have loop : JSON repeat the first row information's. To get every rows informations you have to replace

```
nom : document.querySelector(".td-width h3").textContent,
```

by

```
 nom : tr.children[1].textContent,
```

but in this case you can't precisely target the H3, the links... you get all the  information. So actually I can :

- loop through the rows and get informations, but they unusable
- have only the first row informations but with good presentation

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Probably this Post could help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273739/how-do-scrape-table-from-the-provided-website-using-casperjs/41302965#41302965 You just have to write with the linked solution the results in a Obejct/Array/File as you want.

Comment: Thanks but I've already check this post. 
It's the same problem wich occurs : I can't go precisely inside the row to select the data I want. But more than this, here I don't get all DATAS, only title and description of the company. Wich are in the same <td>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to take information inside every element, you have to use tr.querySelector rather than document.querySelector.

The following loop works fine with the page:

```
var table_rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"); //or better selector
return Array.prototype.map.call(table_rows, function(tr) {
    return {
        nom: tr.querySelector(".td-width h3").textContent,
        description: tr.querySelector(".td-width p").textContent,
        mail: tr.querySelector('td span a[href^="mailto"]').textContent,
        site: tr.querySelector('td span a:not([href^="mailto"])').textContent
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the code obviously, but also for explaining me where I was in wrong way ! That's solved my problem !